# Mysql2::Error 139: DB:FIXTURES:LOAD for LARGE TEXT FIELDS CRASHES the insert process and often corrupts the fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

**PROBLEM**

**Loading fixtures for large text fields crashes the fixture-processing process and often even corrupts the fixture (.yml) file.**

**ENVIRONMENT**

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]; Rails 3.2.6; OSX 10.6.8; **WebBrick**; **and MySQL** ― 8 Gb RAM

**BACKGROUND**

1:  Our project displays a multitude of articles which can regularly
    exceed 5-10,000 words.

2:  Escaped content assigned to records (even of moderate volume)
    crashes fixture processes.

3:  rake db:fixtures:load will crash on the subject .yml file with the
    following error/warning: **Could not determine content-length of
    response body. Set content-length of the response or set
    Response#chunked = true**.

4:  Even when we break this material down into what are quite modest-sized text fields of 1,000 words or less, **db:fixtures:load will still crash on the subject .yml file.**

5:  **Files are often corrupted by the crash.** For example, I can rebuild the fixture from scratch with empty field assignments; I can add and process (db:fixtures:load) a single field at a time **until reaching an apparent processing volume limit,** and when this ultimately crashes the fixture-loading process, errant characters are sometimes reported in the initial few characters of the file; **and even when I delete the last field assignment, that file will no longer run.**

6:  Experimentation has established **that there's an approximately 50k limit on the yml that a fixture can assign to *a single record*.** I have many yml files which successfully assign *to multiple records*, but none which successfully assign more than 50k *to a single record. This experience is uniform across dozens of tables.

6.1:  For example, a principal file that suggests such a threshold **only creates a single record:**

6.1.1:  **If I assign empty field contents to all text fields**, rake db:fixtures:load **succeeds** in creating a record void of its text fields.

6.1.2:  But if I increase the size (k) inserted into that **single record**, field by field, **as soon as I cross the 50k threshold (approximately), the process crashes with the following error:**

> rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Got error 139 from storage engine: INSERT
>   INTO `[table_name]`

6.1.3:  **Yet increasing MySQL buffer sizes has not resolved the problem. I have the exact same limitation.**

6.1.3.1:  Here are my MySQL buffer sizes in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
```

6.1.4:  **I also set chunked to true in *all* instances of webrick/httpresponse.rb as follows:**

```
def initialize(config)
  @config = config
  @logger = config[:Logger]
  @header = Hash.new
  @status = HTTPStatus::RC_OK
  @reason_phrase = nil
  @http_version = HTTPVersion::convert(@config[:HTTPVersion])
  @body = ''
  @keep_alive = true
  @cookies = []
  @request_method = nil
  @request_uri = nil
  @request_http_version = @http_version  # temporary
  @chunked = true # @chunked = false
  @filename = nil
  @sent_size = 0
end
```

None of these attempts had any effect on the issue.

7:  **Thus I deduce the threshold applies to the k assigned to a single record, because I have a number of yml files that exceed 1M.**

**RELATED ISSUES?**

8:  **I see other questions report this same "Set content-length of the response" warning/error.** The instances I read however report the error occurring when viewing pages in WebBrick. This isn't the case in our situation at all (although we are now using WebBrick). **We had the same problem when we were using Mongrel;** but I don't see any evidence that our issue relates at all to the local Ruby web server.

9:  **[204_304_keep_alive.patch](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/2300/204_304_keep_alive.patch): I also see that people suffering this error occurrence arising from web server processes are fixing it by applying the 204_304_keep_alive.patch.** However, particularly as we aren't suffering the error condition in a webserver process, this patch may or may not be relevant to our issue.

10:  I've suffered the same issue on several OSX systems, and on earlier Ruby 1.8/Rails 2.

**QUESTION**

Others **must** be assigning 50k to a single record with fixtures.

**Does anyone know straight-away what we have to configure or otherwise change in our Ruby/Rails/OSX/MySQL environment to overcome this very troubling encumbrance?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL IS LIMITED TO 10 TEXT FIELDS**

**There was a curve to conquering this one:**

The logical course of my experiment to resolve our issue **first** split our one large text field into 14 smaller text fields.

**Thus increasing our MySQL buffer size *would* have fixed our fixture/insert problems, *if* I hadn't split the original text field into 14 separate text fields BEFORE I increased our buffer sizes.** I presumed the 14 modest-sized text fields would have no preclusive effect on tests with the buffer size increases, **[but this afternoon I discovered a MySQL bug report that indicated (for an implementation suffering similar problems) that MySQL only supports up to 10 text fields.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10035) It just *happened* that when I added our 11th of 14 text fields, that I *also* crossed the 50k threshold.**

**All the more reason to write articulate error handlers... it happens *also* that exceeding the 10 text field limit *engenders *the same error* as running out of buffer space!**

Anyway, I hope this experience will steer others around both situations. I have a lot of time in fixing our configuration.

In any case, the rules of thumb are:

1. **Abide by the 10 text field limit for MySQL.**
2. **Deploy sufficient buffer sizes in your /etc/my.cnf.**

Having the spare RAM, I'm running "**my-large.cnf**" for our project's needs.

Comment: Resolution of this issue is further articulated in response to my erroneous bug report at Github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7793